# Talend GlobalMap variable Error, NullPointerException to count my inputrow NB_LINE

Tags: exception, nullpointerexception, talend

I need to count how many inputs I have before starting the component `tDenormalizeSortedRow` (if I put a wrong number of line, the last values are lost).

The problem is that I used a global variable:

```
((Integer)globalMap.get("tConvertType_1_NB_LINE"))
```

But it throws an error:

> Exception in component tJava_1 (TestIDuniqueextract)
> java.lang.NullPointerException

I don't know why the global variable is null:

[image: Schema of the Job]

Comment: Can you please post the code used in tJava as well?

Comment: I removed the Tjava1 but the error still exist : Exception in component tDenormalizeSortedRow_1 
java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global variable return NULL value if you use it in the same flow. So i need to send value to the next subjob with thashoutput/input and then use the global variable

refer to this link :
(https://community.talend.com/s/question/0D53p00007wWjJWCA0/globalmap-variable-error-javalangnullpointerexception)

Regards